# ExtJS: default validation

Tags: extjs, extjs4

95% of my fields for a form I have use a custom validator -> hence I include it as apart of my `defaults` config of the container.

However, for the remaining 5% of fields, I want to use the **built-in validation**. Is there a way to manually specify using the default validator for a given field type?

Currently I try,

```
{
    name: 'normalNumberField',
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    validator: Ext.form.field.Number.validate,
    ...
}
```

but I'm getting an error that `Ext.form` is `undefined` (why? I clearly have a reference to `Ext` ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `validator` is not specified by default.  Number field validation occurs in multiple steps (this is taken from the ExtJS docs):

> 1. **Field specific validator**
>
>    A validator offers a way to customize and reuse a validation specification.  If a field is configured with a `validator`  function,
>      it will be passed the current field value.  The `validator`  function
>      is expected to return either:
>
>    - Boolean `true`  if the value is valid (validation continues).
>    - a String to represent the invalid message if invalid (validation halts).
> 2. **Basic Validation**
>
>    If the `validator` has not halted validation,  basic validation proceeds as follows:
>
>    - `allowBlank` : (Invalid message = `blankText`)
>
>      Depending on the configuration of `allowBlank`, a
>        blank field will cause validation to halt at this step and return
>        Boolean true or false accordingly.
>    - `minLength` : (Invalid message = `minLengthText`)
>
>      If the passed value does not satisfy the `minLength`
>        specified, validation halts.
>    - `maxLength` : (Invalid message = `maxLengthText`)
>
>      If the passed value does not satisfy the `maxLength`
>        specified, validation halts.
> 3. **Preconfigured Validation Types (VTypes)**
>
>    If none of the prior validation steps halts validation, a field 
>      configured with a `vtype` will utilize the  corresponding
>      `Ext.form.field.VTypes` validation function.  If invalid, either the
>      field's `vtypeText` or  the VTypes vtype Text property will be used
>      for the invalid message.  Keystrokes on the field will be filtered
>      according to the VTypes  vtype Mask property.
> 4. **Field specific regex test**
>        If none of the prior validation steps halts validation, a field's  configured `regex` test will be processed.  The
>      invalid message for this test is configured with `regexText`
> 5. **Number field specific validation**
>
>    The additional validations run test  that the value is a number, and
>      that it is within the configured min and max values.

So, long story short, to override your `validator` that you specified in `defaults`, you can simply use a `validator` which always returns `true`.

```
{
    name: 'normalNumberField',
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    validator: function(){ return true; },
    ...
}
```